# Snippets HTML para JSX

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, jsx

Alguém sabe onde posso conseguir Snippets HTML para usar no JavaScript?

**Exemplo:**

input: `h1 + tab`

output: `<h1></h1>`

Comment: Qual editor de texto está usando?

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: Você pode instalar esse -> https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=abusaidm.html-snippets

Comment: Eu já baixei essa, mas só funciona para arquivos .html

Comment: Ele funciona para javascript também precisa configurar: https://github.com/abusaidm/html-snippets/issues/27#issuecomment-282512411

Comment: Funcionou! Valeu mesmo cara.

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa primeiro baixar o plugin que disponibiliza os `snippets` HTML, [Exemplos para download aqui](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=abusaidm.html-snippets).

Em seguida, você precisa configurar o `VS Code` e/ou o `snippet` para que ele funcione também em outras extensões.

Para configurar ([tutorial para configuração](https://github.com/abusaidm/html-snippets/issues/27#issuecomment-282512411)):

Ir para o diretório `extensions`, geralmente localizado em:

```
Windows %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions
Mac ~/.vscode/extensions
Linux ~/.vscode/extensions
```

Ache o diretório da extensão que deseja, exemplo `abusaidm.html-snippets-x.x.x`, onde x.x.x é a versão.

Abra o arquivo `package.json` dentro dele.

Adicione o trecho abaixo dentro da seção de `snippets`, configurando a extensão/linguagem que desejar.

```
,{
     "language": "NOVA LINGUAGEM / EXTENSÃO",
     "path": "./snippets/snippets.json"
}
```